# Django: using __str__ with a foreignkey in order to return an item

Tags: django

I am simply trying to override the **str** method to return something from a foreign key. A snippet of my models is as follows:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    shortened_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_creation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    history = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', args=[self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.shortened_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse('add_to_cart', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

class ShoppingCartOrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.product.name
```

After adding the item to my shopping cart, in the admin panel when trying to view the specific item I get an AttributeError: 'ShoppingCartOrderItem' object has no attribute 'product'. Based on my googling so far I don't see why this isn't working. I have even tried str(self.product.name) but still the same error produces. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be `return self.item.name`, since you named the `ForeignKey` `item`, *not* `product`.

Comment: Ahh I am stupid for overlooking something so simple. Thank you very much!